# I was thinking of her(,) swimming in the lake

Tags: punctuation, semantics, grammatical-roles, participial-phrases

Do we place a comma before 'swimming' in 'I was thinking of her swimming in the lake.'?
How can it be rephrased?

1. I was thinking of her while I was swimming in the lake.
2. She swimming in the lake was on my mind for a while.
3. Her swimming in the lake was on my mind for a while.

How does the prosody affect the interpretation?

Comment: (1) implies that you were swimming, the others that you were remembering/imagining the sight of her swimming. Which is it?

Comment: 2) is very awkward.

Answer (score 0):

> I was thinking of her swimming in the lake.

In this sentence, the absence of a comma results in the phrase "her swimming in the lake" having the nature of a noun phrase, where the  "*swimming*" acts as the head. Rather than considering "swimming" as a past participle, we acknowledge it as the verbal noun.

> (**SOED**) **swimming** 1 The action of SWIM *v*; an instance of this.

It follows that the person who is writing or speaking is thinking either of the action (how well she swam, for example, or how long, etc.) or of this particular case of having a swim, whereas that person also has in mind her swimming in other places, such as a pool, or simply considering this instance independently of any other. There are two paraphrases.

- I was thinking of the motions of her body as she swam in the lake.
- I was thinking of her swim in the lake.

> I was thinking of her, swimming in the lake.

If we now use a comma, the sentence is not correct; the phrase  "swimming in the lake" can't be a noun phrase: separating a unique determiner (*her*) from its noun makes no sense; it follows that "her" is not a determiner but a pronoun. However, the phrase "swimming in the lake", which you have to reckon with now as a participial clause is unattached; grammarians also say that it has a dangling participle; that is to say the subject of the participle is unclear: is the author swimming in the lake or is it the person whom they are talking about that is swimming in the lake? Such sentences can sometimes be acceptable, as the next one for instance.

- Considering its cost, this machine is not worth buying. (**CoGEL**)

Consequently, "1" is a possible interpretation of this latter formulation, whic, with its pendant participle, is incorrect. "2" is the other possibility that results from the error. "3" is a paraphrasing of "1".

In conclusion, let's say that no comma should used, and that when it is used, according to the context, both  "2" and "3" can be a correct paraphrase. "2" can only refer to the "instance" part (SOED definition of "swimming"), whereas "3" can refer to both ("action" or "instance").